# PHP shell command not working

Tags: php

I am trying to run the following command from PHP

```
openssl enc -base64 -in <( openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac echkrHQpoaK8LV4ROplB8vQiY9r1dQf0  <( echo -n "POST application/json a5d3867576a72ad3d981f91032f32aff6b81435ea226807e32f322b20b711a54 2017-02-22T16:55:14Z /user/2"))
```

But I keep getting the error

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

sh: -c: line 0: `openssl enc -base64 -in <( openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac echkrHQpoaK8LV4ROplB8vQiY9r1dQf0  <( echo -n "POST application/json a5d3867576a72ad3d981f91032f32aff6b81435ea226807e32f322b20b711a54 2017-02-22T16:55:14Z /transaction/v23"))'
```

I have used shell_exc(), exec(), system() and backticks `` and they all give me the same output.

I am using PHP 7 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server and also in a CentOS 7 server.
The command runs as expected with a valid output when run directly in the shell.

I am at a lost here. Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share the php code?

Comment: What means `from PHP` here ? That code part must be missing...

Comment: Did you know http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php ?

Comment: Thank you for your response JustOneUnderMillions. What I mean from PHP is I have a php script with the lines below. I have checked the escapeshellargs and escapeshellcmd but I am still not getting anywhere with them either. `$command = "openssl enc -base64 -in <( openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -hmac echkrHQpoaK8LV4ROplB8vQiY9r1dQf0  <( echo -n \"POST application/json a5d3867576a72ad3d981f91032f32aff6b81435ea226807e32f322b20b711a54 2017-02-22T16:55:14Z /transaction/v23\"))";
        $output = exec($command);
        var_dump($output);`